# how to save visited page url id in same cookie .net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

Hi I want to save my last visited product detail page id in one cookie. For ex.first, ı am at random tire page  and first cookie value 44 then visiting other pages url id 65 one by one. what should ı do? Can ı save them in List for cookie value because it's what ı need? thanks for helps.

```
       public ActionResult DetailShow(int id)
    {
        string cokvalue = ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();

        List<string> view = new List<string>();


        foreach (var item in cokvalue)
        {
            view.Add(cokvalue);


        }

        **This one for What ı want to add last visited pages

        HttpCookie cok = new HttpCookie("last viewed");
        cok.Values["last visited"] = string.Join(",", view.ToArray());
        cok.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cok);

        HttpCookie mycookie = new HttpCookie("Product");
        mycookie.Values["asd"] = cokvalue;
        mycookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(mycookie);




        var product = gelistirmeEntities.Product.Where(p => p.Product_ID == id).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(product);

    }
```

Comment: Please add your code or a test case to this question. Then people may help to fix what's wrong.

Comment: You should not transform a question into a non-question: instead, post your solution separately in its own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THE ANSWER

```
public ActionResult DetailShow(int id)
{
    string cokvalue = ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
    HttpCookie cok = Request.Cookies["last viewed"];
    List<string> cookielist = new List<string>();
    cookielist.Add(cokvalue);


    if (cok == null)
    {
        var serialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cookielist);
        cok = new HttpCookie("last viewed");
        cok.Values["last visited"] = serialize;


    }

    else
    {                
        cookielist.InsertRange(0,JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(cok.Values["last visited"]));                                
        var serialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cookielist);                
        cok.Values["last visited"] = serialize;


    }
    cok.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cok);

    HttpCookie mycookie = new HttpCookie("Product");
    mycookie.Values["asd"] = cokvalue;
    mycookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(mycookie);


    var product = gelistirmeEntities.Product.Where(p => p.Product_ID == id).FirstOrDefault();

    return View(product);

}
```